# Network ( routing and switching) , security

Tags: routing, nat, switching, network-core, network-access

In my company network i am installing new cisco2811 router but i have problem, my LAN network can not ping and access network. i get point to point internet from ISP.

PTP IP is `192.186.86.200/24` and its switch port is 15 shown in picture.

LAN network IP `172.16.16.200/24` DHCP.

I have configured virtual interfaces in router.

Also implemented NAT rule but i don't now how to access internet.

My internet IP is `192.186.86.200/24`.

I think I need to configure a NAT rule but don't know which type.

This is the router config:

```
Router#show running-config
Building configuration...


Current configuration : 3700 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 18:10:56 UTC Thu Sep 20 2018
version 15.1
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable password Ylinx
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
dot11 syslog
ip source-route
!
!
ip cef
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.16.16.200
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.2.60.55
!
ip dhcp pool YLINX_LAN
 network 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
 default-router 172.16.16.200
 lease 10
 update arp
!
ip dhcp pool YLINX_SERVERS
 network 10.2.60.0 255.255.255.0
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
 default-router 10.2.60.200
 lease 10
 update arp
!
!
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
voice-card 0
!
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-2879905090
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-2879905090
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-2879905090
!
!

    quit
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2811 sn FHK0902F4V6
username naseer secret 5 $1$w6HC$W9eoccnVIhNDKbMr91f2e0
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.400
 encapsulation dot1Q 400
 ip address 192.168.86.200 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.401
 encapsulation dot1Q 401
 ip address 192.168.1.200 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.402
 encapsulation dot1Q 402
 ip address 172.16.16.200 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.403
 encapsulation dot1Q 403
 ip address 10.2.60.200 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface BRI0/1/0
 no ip address
 encapsulation hdlc
 shutdown
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip nat outside source static 192.168.86.200 172.16.16.200
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.86.1 10
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 50
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
mgcp profile default
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 password Ylinx
 login
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 password Ylinx
 login
 transport input all
line vty 5 15
 password Ylinx
 login
 transport input all
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Switch interfaces config:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15 
 description YLINX_PTP
 switchport access vlan 400
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode access

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
 description YLINX_161_DIRECT
 switchport access vlan 402
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode access

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
 description YLINX_CISCO_ROUTER
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q 
 switchport mode trunk

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21 
 description YLINX_SERVERS
 switchport access vlan 403
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode access
```

Comment: ths is point to point(ISP) link IP

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nbhatti/45f6784d50c26f91729bcc6517889c57#file-gistfile1-txt-L29

Comment: my internet poiny to point IP

Comment: Can you include a simple diagram?  It's hard to see how devices are connected just from the router config.  Does your ISP and internal LAN connect via a single trunk?

Comment: One thing for sure:  if the router connect to gi 1/0/15, it should be `switchport mode trunk`.

Comment: yes router connect to trunk mode sir you can check in router configuration

Comment: i think NAT rule will apply for access the internet

Comment: On your switch configuration, the port is set to access.  You need to set it to trunk mode.

Comment: You question is also asking about security, but you do not have any security in your configuration. You either need a separate firewall (where you would then put the NAT), or you need an IOS code with a software firewall for security. Simply hanging the router on the public Internet without a firewall is asking for it to be broken into.

Comment: hi how i can access internet which type of NAT rule implement

Comment: Hi Waleed and welcome.  Please be aware you need to change your router passwords on your equipment as you've included them in your post; even encrypted ones are unwise to share.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Network Engineering!  There are a few things wrong here:

1. There is no inside nat statement.  You have the outside NAT statement on fa 0/0.401.  On your internal LAN interface (whichever that is), you need

   ip nat inside
2. If you simply want internal hosts to reach the internet, change your NAT statement to:

   ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0.401 overload

   access-list 1 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255

If you want external hosts to make connections to internal hosts (like a web server), you need a different NAT statement, but you need to provide more information before we can recommend a configuration.

Comment: configure terminal
ip nat inside source static 172.16.16.200 192.168.86.200
interface FastEthernet0/0.402
encapsulation dot1Q 402
ip address 172.16.16.200 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
interface FastEthernet0/0.400
encapsulation dot1Q 400
ip address 192.168.86.200 255.255.255.0
ip nat outside

Comment: i have implement many NAT rule but not access internet

Comment: ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0.401 overload

access-list 1 permit 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255

Comment: ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0.401 overload access-list 1 permit 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255

Comment: sir where i will implement this NAT rule i have not FastEthernet0/0.401 interface

Comment: this rule will be implement in inside LAN virtual interface

Comment: My mistake.  Make that  0/0.400.

Comment: Is ok sir let me check

Answer (score 0):

Configure  ISP allocated public ip address to router egress interfàce . And further configured Port address translation (PAT) for internet access (outbound traffic)

Static NAT one to one for inbound traffic

**For PAT configuration**

`Router(config) # access-list 10 permit 172.16.16.0 0.0.0.0.255 any`

`Router(config) # ip nat inside source list 1 interfàce F0/1 overload`